# ActiveMq and Camel example in Servlet Code

Tags: servlets, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am looking for a servlet example of Camel and ActiveMq. [No Spring].

Any suggestion/link/resource/code is much appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a servlet example without spring here

- http://camel.apache.org/servlet-tomcat-no-spring-example.html